# push first few elements of an array into 2d array

Tags: php, arrays

Edit :

i Want a structure like this

```
'categories' => [
        [
            'name' => "science" ,
            'questions' =>  [
                [
                    'question' => 'C1_Q2',
                    'answer'   => 'C1_A2',
                ],
                [
                    'question' => 'C1_Q3',
                    'answer'   => 'C1_A3',
                ]
            ]
        ]
```

but with help of loop

I am trying to create a questionnaire in which 3 steps need to be done

Create 3 arrays

1.categories - 2d  -- like category["science"]["questions"]

2.questions

3.answers

step 1. add 10 questions in question array and add 10 answers in answer arrays

step 2.first 5 question of question array should be inserted to categories["science"]["questions"] and 5 answers to categories["science"]
["answers"]

I created Question and answer array and added 10 , 10 elements in it . but didnt succeed to add its elements as per step2 . I tried few logic

```
$Category=array();
$Q=array();
$A=array();

for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
{
$Q[] = "Question post".$i;
$A[] = "Answer post".$i;


//if($i==5)
//{
//  array_push($Category,$Q[i]);
//  break;
//} ---logic not working

}

//array first 5 Questions to category array
/* 
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
{
//$Category[]=$Q[i];
array_push($Category,$Q[i]);
}
 */ -- not working 

print_r($Category);
```

Any suggestion or help would be appreciated

Comment: You need to show an actual example of the arrays to be more clear.

Comment: updated question

Comment: ok , array_push($Category,$Q[$i]);  start working , but Can i get something more specific like  $Category['science'['question']] = 'first question set' ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$questions = [];
$answers = [];
for($i=1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $questions[] = 'Question post' . $i;
    $answers[] = 'Answer post' . $i;
}
$categories = ['science', 'something', 'else'];
$result = [];
foreach ($questions as $index => $question) {
    if ($index % 5 != 0 || $index == 0) {
        $category = current($categories);
    } else {
        $category = next($categories);
    }
    $result[$category][] = ['question' => $question, 'answer' => $answers[$index]];
}
var_dump($result);
```